# If I am using 2 weapons, can I trip with one and attack the tripped target in the same round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

I'm playing a dual wield fighter and I was wondering is it possible to, when using a full round action to attack and you have more then one strike, can you trip with your first hit and then proceed to attack the tripped target?

Put a little more simply, Can I trip with one weapon then attack with the other in one turn? Or is Trip a full round action?

Clearing up one thing, I am using a trip weapon.

Answer (score 15):

**Yes,** you can trip and attack in the same turn.

Trip, sunder, and disarm replace a single melee attack and thus can be interspersed in any order in multiple attack routines, as part of a flurry of blows, and as an attack of opportunity. This is clear from the [descriptions of the maneuvers in the SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Combat-Maneuvers).

Of course, these may provoke attacks of opportunity of their own, and other feats and weapons you may have might affect number of attacks and bonuses thereto.  In our pirate campaign just today, we had a monk consistently tripping first in his flurries to benefit from the lowered AC of the prone opponent, and a big barbarian who would use his lower-to-hit second attack on disarms since he figured on the off chance he connects it might as well mess with the opponent more than just some damage.  Make sure and read the prone rules and other related areas to understand how all this will work.

Answer (score 12):

Tripping replaces a single attack, and you may still make any other attacks you’d otherwise be entitled to. Note that there are also a pair of feats ([Improved Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/improved-trip-combat---final) and [Greater Trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-trip-combat---final)) to get a free attack (as an Attack of Opportunity) against the guy you tripped, which would not count against your regular limit (but is limited by your number of Attacks of Opportunity).

Comment: Since the feat table is huge, can you link/note which feat(s) allows the AoO on an opponent you just tripped?

Comment: @Pulsehead Sure, done.